# Does math.random assume 0 to be an integer?

Tags: android, math, random

So, does `int random = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);` return a value of 0,1,2,3,4 rather than 1,2,3,4,5?

I have tried to test this, but it never seems to hit 0 or 5 =x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, `Math.random()` will always return a value greater than or equal to 0, and strictly less than 1.

So using `(int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)` should actually give you 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. However, any value returned from `Math.random()` other than *exactly* 0 will be give a value of 1 or more after the call to `Math.ceil()` - so you will see 0 vanishingly often. (You'll be lucky if you *ever* see it, but it's definitely *possible*.) Seeing 5 is easy - you'll get that any time `Math.random()` returns a value greater than 0.8.

Is there any reason you're not using `Random.nextInt()` instead?

Comment: Although it should give you 0 very, very rarely.

Comment: I am not familiar with Random.nextInt() - is it a better way to generate a random #?

Comment: @rob: I was just adding that :) @Sapp: Yes. It gives you a lot more control over seeds etc, *and* helpful methods for getting integers in a range etc.

Comment: @Sapp: Look at the API docs for the `Random` class - you'll find the information you need. (Google "Java 6 Random" for the Java version, or use the Android API search for the Android version)

Comment: Ok great - does nextint() just give a more randomly generated #?

Comment: @Sapp: No, that's not the point - it's that it lets you specify the range yourself, so you don't need to worry about multiplication, calling `ceil` etc. Its construction is also more flexible, allowing for different seeds and more cryptographically random sources such as `SecureRandom`.